# Loading a VIEW from the Welcome Page by clicking in an image in Eclipse Java Desktop Application

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, desktop-application

In the Welcome Page of my Java Eclipse application I keep different images. For this I use the code in the `.xhtml` file which is as follows:

```
<div class="icon">
<img src="../icons/account.png" width="64" height="64" />
</div>
```

Now, I need to load a particular `VIEW` by clicking on the image of the Welcome Page. Each `VIEW` has a different `Id` which is defined in the `MANIFEST.MF`.
Can anybody help me with the code after `<img src="../icons/account.png" width="64" height="64" />` in the `XHTML` file. I have tried the code that we use for Website application but it did not work.

Comment: Do you mean ViewPart? And instead of MANIFEST.MF, mean plugin.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is to invoke an action from a  link in the page. [this section in the help](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_intro_extending.htm) shows you how to do that.